# my editor vs code on mac is replacing tabs with spaces and I want it to stop

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, spaces

my editor is replacing tabs with spaces and I want it to stop.  To be clear, when I press tab the editor puts 2 spaces where the cursor is and I want it to put 1 tab because the current behavior is messing with the WordPress coding Standards.  I have looked up about 1000 articles from google searches on how to fix this and nothing is working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you disabled the settings: `Editor: Insert Spaces` and `Editor: Detect Indentation`?

Comment: Ok that was it, you need to disable both.  I have had insert spaces and detect indentation enabled and disabled at different times but never together.  Ok so the answer here was to disable both of those options at the same time.  Feel free to answer that as a solution and I'll give you the best solution checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable both of these settings:

`Editor: Insert Spaces`

> // Insert spaces when pressing `Tab`. This setting is overridden based
> on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.

and

`Editor: Deteect Indentation`

> // Controls whether `editor.tabSize#` and `#editor.insertSpaces` will
> be automatically detected when a file is opened based on the file
> contents.

Comment: the two settings need to be false

Comment: Disabling in the Settings Ui - unchecking the checkbox, is the same as setting `editor.detectIndentation` to false for example.